# Android Restricting file to applications

Tags: android

Android Application Development ::

Is there any way to restrict/moderate the access of file created by one application to other applications/file explorers?

Ex: App ABC created file file.txt

Now, file.txt could only be accessed (access mode 700 in Linux Structure) by ABC app. This file should also be hidden/secured from file explorer apps.

Context: This could be a settings file such as JSON/XML which should be made private only to this application but stored in ext. mem card (I can use assets folder but this file keeps adding new settings to the existing settings eventually).

Any Ideas??

Answer (score 2):

Anything on the external storage is world readable.

If you need to store data private to your app, your options are Shared Preferences, or Internal storage.

See the [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) page at the Android Developer site for samples of using each type of storage.